# Good and easy way to create a paper tuning jig

Tags: archery, diy

I need to do paper tuning in a few days. Is there any recommendation on how to quickly setup a paper tuning jig?

I'm in a shooting range, so I basically need the jig (frame holding the paper) only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardboard box with a hole in it. Tape the paper over the hole.

If your range has a place to mount the cardboard, you only need a single side of the box. If not take the whole box and cut entrance AND exit holes in it.  Optimally the arrow should pass all the way through the paper without touching anything but the paper.

If you need to elevate the box, just bring more boxes, you can stack them.  New moving/storage boxes are available for less than a dollar.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've used a fruit cardboard box and clamped it in a target stand. As you've suggested I cut in a hole and glued paper in it. Worked like a charm! Thanks for that.